# ThreeJS OBJMTLLoader not loading mtl with parameters

Tags: javascript, three.js

My mtl has lines like these:

map_bump -bm 0.3000 Map__1_Wood.jpg

And when I am using the threejs objmtlloader example for my model I get such errors:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/models/-bm%200.3000%20Map__1_Wood.jpg

Clearly it fails to parse parameters correctly. Has anyone met this problem before?

Comment: remove the `-bm 0.3000`. It is not supported.

Comment: I reported in threejs github and they closed my issue.. I guess they don't plan to support it?